# Create arrow without fill using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Creating a triangle using CSS is pretty easy and common practice, but is it possible to create a triangle in a similar way with a transparent background and just a border.

This is what I would like to create:

[image: Scroll Triangle]

Given the way triangles are typically made, I dont really know where to start as they rely on pseudo elements and overlapping borders etc. This obviously cannot be done if the border is transparent...

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: http://codepen.io/jonneal/pen/kptBs

Comment: @Jakemmarsh Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: was about to do that :-)

Comment: Is there a way to pull the ends farther apart, like skewing them, maintaining the triangle but not a perfect right angle.

Comment: @Omar Just change the values in the rotation.

Comment: Instead of two div's you can put a :before and :after pseudo in an element.

Comment: @098764 They are two separate controls! One for down facing and other for up facing. They aren't meant to be used together... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thought you used them as two filled up divs. I see now :) I nice solution indeed.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I added a solution with pseudo elements below.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a pseudo-element to insert a character from this list:

- Countersink: `⌵` (U+2335)
- Latin capital letter v: `V` (U+0056)
- Latin small letter v: `v` (U+0076)
- Mathematical sans-serif capital v:  (U+1d5b5)
- Mathematical sans-serif small v:  (U+1d5cf)
- N-ary logical or: `⋁` (U+22c1)
- Roman numeral five: `Ⅴ` (U+2164)
- Small roman numeral five: `ⅴ` (U+2174)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: .75em;
}
div:after {
  content: '⌵';
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<div>Scroll down</div>
```

Comment: No downvote from me. Thank you very much, just what I needed!! +1

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Even I am using Chrome. What's the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I concur! :-P. Anyone know why the question was downvoted?

Comment: IMO Firefox displays `⌵` prettier than Chrome, but there it looks good too.

Comment: BTW I'm on Win10. latest chrome. FYI Firefox has a built-in character library support that Chrome has not.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Strange, it works on Chromium 45 on WinXP for me.

Comment: @Oriol I know it's strange. let me see the range of that character... brb

Comment: Yuck. I have no clue. It works on my Windows 10, Chrome *some 10000! LoL... Chrome keeps on updating. Should be the latest, lazy to check the version.*

Comment: Win:10; CH:44.0.2403.155 m (up-to-date) http://i.imgur.com/h3oHptM.jpg (<< char at 9013). Strange. I would bet I had almost all those ranges in WinXP a month ago...

Answer (score 1):

Use Font-awesome, [chevron-down](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-down/)

```css
.blk {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
}

.blk .fa {
  color: white;
  margin: 40px 50% auto 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="blk">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw something about this on another post. Its not what I was looking for but thank you very much anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with pseudo-elements. Appliable to any kind of element.

```css
.class:before {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.class:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-left: -7px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{background:#000;color:#fff;font: 16px/1 sans-serif;}
h2{text-align:center;}

.arrowDown{
  position:relative;
}
.arrowDown:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left:         50%;
  bottom:     -16px;
  width:       16px;
  height:      16px;
  margin-left: -8px; /* (16/2) */
  border-right:  3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="arrowDown">Scroll down</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be to use SVG to create the shape.

```css
.scroll_down {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.scroll_down p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll_down">
  <p>Scroll Down</p>
  <svg width="20px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
    <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="white" d="M1,1 L10,9 L19,1"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

It's well supported and relatively easy to use.