# Creating CSS Triangles with no 'side'?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS Triangle that looks like this `>` without the left side to it. I am doing this on a `div` with the `:after` property and I know I can just append a `>` with the `content: ''` style, but as would like to use a triangle because I have more control on things such as size and proportion.

That being said, here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
content:"";
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 20px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 30.5px 0 30.5px 50px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
line-height: 0px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

I've tried removing and editing the `border-width` and `border-color` styles to remove that flat size, but just can't seem to get the look I'm going for.

Is this possible with just CSS?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrL5yb90/)**

Comment: by "Triangle" do you mean "Chevron"?

Comment: Yes, that would be a great way to explain it, thanks!

Comment: And this also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999159/create-arrow-without-fill-using-css

Comment: Thanks Harry and Aaron, the duplicate this was marked with by web-tiki has answered my question.

Comment: Try like this https://jsfiddle.net/fabric/vrL5yb90/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
div:before {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  left: 0;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```